# Should close $wpdb via $wpdb->close()

Tags: wp-query, database, wpdb

I’ve been writing a few custom plugins for my site and I was wondering about the correct way to interact with $wpdb.
My plugin executes a few queries using the global $wpdb connection.
I noticed that a $wpdb->close(); method has been added to WordPress, to close the database connection object.

My question is: Should a plugin close out the connection after executing queries?

I have been searched on the folder of some famous plugin(like rank math, Yoast). they use $wpdb a lot but I could  not find $wpdb->close() on their code. I mean at the end of their function they do not close query.

for example, I have been writing a function for counting post from last week

```
    function get_posts_count_from_last_week($post_type = 'post')
 {
        global $wpdb;
        $numposts = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(ID) " . "FROM " . $wpdb->posts . " WHERE post_status='publish' AND post_type= %s AND post_date> %s", $post_type, date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-168 hours'))));
        return $numposts;

}
```

I get a lot of `“WordPress database error Commands out of sync; you can’t run this command now for query SELECT”`
So I have to put `$wpdb->close();` before return and after that I did not get `Commands out of sync` at all.

I confuse, why I have to close the connection when other plugins don't do that!
by the way in my theme I have some functions with `global $wpdb` but, again there is not any `$wpdb->close()` for closing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The `close()` function was added for completeness in the database abstraction.](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/34903) If the database is prematurely closed in a plugin or theme (as you are using it), [the next call to `wpdb::query()` will re-open the connection.](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/34903#comment:4)

Your `Commands out of sync` error is a [MySQL error](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commands-out-of-sync.html), not a WordPress one, and it might be coming from a plugin or theme that you're using. Googling for `wordpress database commands out of sync` comes up with a lot of possible issues, including caching plugins. Try disabling all plugins and switching to a default theme (like Twenty Twenty); if the issue goes away, turn plugins back on till you find the culprit. Then contact that plugin's support crew.